# Format for D3's data() binding

Tags: d3.js

What is the required format for things passed to d3's `.data()`?

In this jsfiddle, I try to create several `<div>` elements for each metric. Unfortunately, nothing happens. I'm assuming this is related to an incorrect data structure?

http://jsfiddle.net/GppWz/

Answer (score 1):

The main issue here is that you are trying to use a hash as a data source, while d3 wants your data in array format.

If you can, modify your data source so that you are receiving data in array format. If this is not possible, you can use the [`d3.entries`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_entries) function to convert the object into an array:

```
var listContainers = d3.select('#lists').selectAll('div')
  .data(d3.entries(data))
  .enter().append('div')
  .attr('class', 'listContainer');
listContainers.append('h5')
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.key;
  });
var item = listContainers.selectAll('.item').data(function(d) {
  return d.value;
}).enter()
  .append('div')
  .attr('class', 'item')
  .text(function(d) {
    return 'average_dif = ' + d.average_dif;
  });
// ...
```